# How to map multiple classes to single table with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a domain that defines two objects: `Property` and `Address`. They have a one-to-one relationship where every `Property` has an `Address`.

I would like to have a single table that holds the `Property` and `Address` data in order to avoid a unnecessary join when queries `Properties`:

```
create table properties
(
id integer primary key,
name varchar(50) not null,
address_city varchar(50) not null
)
```

And have the bellow classes definitions:

```
class Property(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name, address):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.address = address

class Address(object):
    def __init__(self, city):
        self.city = city
```

How can I configure the SQLAlchemy mappers to support this kind of structure? (I saw inheritance configurations but it doesn't fit my case)

Comment: Why do you think that the join is unnecessary? I think that's the best way to do it.

Comment: @Alex because it is a one-to-one must have relationship so avoid the join will make queries faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though in general I'd vote for creating separate *property* and *address* relations, with suitable foreign key constraints, you can map your classes to a single table using a [composite column type](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/composites.html):

```
In [2]: class Address:
   ...:     def __init__(self, city):
   ...:         self.city = city
   ...:     def __composite_values__(self):
   ...:         # NOTE: returns a 1-tuple
   ...:         return self.city,
   ...:     def __repr__(self):
   ...:         return "Address(city={!r})".format(self.city)
   ...:     def __eq__(self, other):
   ...:         return isinstance(other, Address) and self.city == other.city
   ...:     def __ne__(self, other):
   ...:         return not self.__eq__(other)

In [3]: class Property(Base):
   ...:     __tablename__ = "properties"
   ...:     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   ...:     name = Column(Unicode(50), nullable=False)
   ...:     address_city = Column(Unicode(50), nullable=False)
   ...:     address = composite(Address, address_city)
   ...: 
   ...:     def __init__(self, name, address):
   ...:         self.name = name
   ...:         self.address = address
```

With the above type and model you can then create new properties:

```
In [5]: session.add(Property('Ye Olde House', Address('London')))

In [6]: session.commit()
```

and query:

```
In [7]: session.query(Property).\
   ...:     filter_by(address=Address('London')).\
   ...:     first()
Out[7]: <__main__.Property at 0x7f02dd8892e8>

In [8]: _.address.city
Out[8]: 'London'
```

---

In the coming Python 3.7 that implements [PEP 557 – Data Classes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/) the `Address` class could be defined as:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, astuple

@dataclass
class Address:
    city: str

    def __composite_values__(self):
        return astuple(self)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's exactly what I needed.